# Keep 1 Week Data in database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have some data in my database 
this data updates everyday
i want to keep only 1 week data in my database
i dont want data older than 1 week

can anyone tell me how to delete all the data except the one week data from database

Comment: database is mysql, oracle?? also version??

Comment: Besides, in your database or in a particular table??

Comment: MYSQL Version is 5.1
@MostyMostacho in a table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set up a cron job to check when data is older than a week. Then delete using a where clause.

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(),TimeStampColumn) > 7
```

Answer (score 0):

The [RRDtool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RRDtool) database format and bindings provide easy access to round-robin database capabilities in a variety of languages; RRD is the de-facto standard for many system monitoring tools.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way: make sure the entry date/time is recorded for all data in the db and run a cron to periodically remove all data older than a week.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options.

**1.Event Scheduler**

First create table and create event for perform delete query for delete 1 weeks ago record.

```
CREATE EVENT `ex1` ON SCHEDULE
EVERY 1 DAY
ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE
ENABLE
COMMENT ''
DO BEGIN
DELETE FROM table WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(),TimeStampColumn) > 7

END
//for 3 weeks
```

Note : Old versions of mysql don't have event scheduler

**2. Create cron job**

**file1.sql**

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(),TimeStampColumn) > 7
```

**schedule this command:**

mysql -uusername -ppassword < /path/to/file1.sql